# admin / admin does not work on Superset install through Google Cloud Marketplace

Tags: apache-superset

I have installed Superset using Google Cloud Marketplace onto GKE.

However, when I tried to login using admin/admin, it doesn't work.

During the installation, I also don't recall having an option to set the password.

Is there something that I have missed?